# What is the Right Way to install pip3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python3, pip

An alert while running pip3 sent me to some advice to "Only ever use your system package manager to upgrade the system pip." This was the original alert:

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail
> in a future version of pip. Please see
> https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the
> underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m
> pip' instead of running pip directly.

I don't see `pip` or `pip3` in my existing repositories. Is there a right way to fix this, consistent with the best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has `pip` available in the packages `python3-pip` for python3 or `python-pip` for python2.